# Flask and sqlalchemy: Receiving a "can't adapt type 'ABCMeta'" error when posting to database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I try to create a new user in the database I receive an error that reads
`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'ABCMeta'`

I've seen similar responses to this error here, but I am unsure of what this error is telling me.

Would anyone be able to give me clarity on what this error means and how can I solve it?

Code:

```
from extensions import db



class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

    recipes = db.relationship('Recipe', backref='user')


    @classmethod
    def get_user_by_username(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    @classmethod
    def get_user_by_email(cls, email):
        return cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

Error:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 828-615-892
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2022 16:15:10] "POST /users HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1820, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ABCMeta'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/resources/user.py", line 31, in post
    user.save()
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/models/user.py", line 29, in save
    db.session.commit()
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
    
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1435, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3367, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3507, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3467, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 633, in execute
    uow,
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 250, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1241, in _emit_insert_statements
    execution_options=execution_options,
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 326, in _execute_on_connection
    self, multiparams, params, execution_options
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1508, in _execute_clauseelement
    cache_hit=cache_hit,
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1863, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2044, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1820, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/Users/lawrence/Documents/smilecook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'ABCMeta'
[SQL: INSERT INTO "user" (username, email, password, is_active) VALUES (%(username)s, %(email)s, %(password)s, %(is_active)s) RETURNING "user".id]
[parameters: {'username': 'ray', 'email': 'ray@gmail.com', 'password': <class 'passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256'>, 'is_active': False}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `password` value you are trying to save is not a string, as the typing of the `password` column suggests you intended, but a class -- specifically, the class `passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256`. I think maybe you meant to call that class when you were setting the value of password (i.e., do this: `password = passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256()`, with the parentheses), but you instead set it to the class you intended to call (i.e., did this: `password = passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256`, without the parentheses).

I'm not totally sure what is going on with that particular error you are getting, but it suggests that the meta class of `passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256` is `ABCMeta`, which would be the case if `passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha256` is an abstract class.